# Does using try/catch prevent return value from mysqli::prepare()?

Tags: php, mysqli

According to this PHP documentation on [mysqli::prepare()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), it appears that the return value should be a statement object or `false`.

In the example below, I made a mistake in changing an INSERT INTO to a REPLACE INTO, and the error-handler code never executed but the `catch` picked up a 1064 error.

Is this the expected behavior?  Why didn't `$db->prepare($sql)` return `false`?  Does using `try/catch` pick up the error before the return?

Thank you.

```
try {
  $sql = " INSERT REPLACE INTO ... WHERE id=?";
  if ( !($stmt = $db->prepare($sql) ) ) {
    /* error handler code */
  }
} catch ( Exception $err ) {
  $res['r'] = $err->getCode();
  $res['m'] = $err->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This entirely depends on how you've configured [mysqli_report()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.mysqli-report.php). In your case, it looks like you've got it throwing exceptions which will happen instead of any value being returned from `prepare()`, `execute()`, etc

Comment: @Phil What is supposed to be done with duplicate questions?  Am I to delete it?

Comment: There's some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) but in general, I don't think you need to do anything. Leaving your question here can help boost SEO for the _canonical_ answer.

Comment: Yes, this is how exceptions work, exactly. But obviously, it not a "try catch" that prevents the returning of value, but *throw*, called internally by prepare(). While having try-catch doesn't change anything here. But in the first place, why do you have *two handlers*? What's the use of this $res['r'] and $res['m']?

Comment: Why do you catch errors at all? If you have an error in your SQL that should result in a fatal error, unless you have a way to recover from it.